# Wordpress Banner / PHP - Check if a certain image file exists, otherwise use a fallback banner

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Is this possible. I want to do something like the wordpress header/theme having a default image banner, but it won't use it unless the specified image file does not exist.

The logic should work like this
if (this img file does not exist) then use (this default/fallback image as banner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
if (file_exists($img)){
    echo "<img src='$img' alt=''>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='fallback_image.jpg' alt=''>";
}
```

You might need to specify more details in your question if not, but file_exists() should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the answer. What I want now is to define the $img variable into the image file location. May I ask for an example, should it be absolute/relative path?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with WordPress, although relative is generally better if you can get it to work.